# How to find curvature of curve with vectors

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-spaces, vectors, curvature

The question is as follows:

---

Let $\vec{a}, \vec{b} \in \mathbb{R}^3$ be given,

Consider the curve $\vec{r}(t) = \vec{OP_{0}} + t\vec{a} + t^2\vec{b}$, $t \in \mathbb{R}$

Find the curvature of the curve at $\vec{r}(0)$.

---

I have just started learning about arc-lengths and paremetrizations, and I have no clue how to approach this question. I've tried splitting each vector in the function to its components (e.g. $\vec{a} \rightarrow (a_1, a_2, a_3))$, but I can't progress any further. I'm wondering how to incorporate the curvature formula for this question;

$$\frac{\vec{r}'(t) \times \vec{r}''(t)}{\left|\vec{r(t)}\right|^3}$$

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula is $$\kappa=\frac{||\dot r \times \ddot r||}{(\dot r \bullet \dot r)^{3/2}}$$ Your notation is really unfortunate, since the vector $a$ usually denotes the acceleration vector, i.e. $\ddot r,$ but I'll stick with that bad notation.
$$\dot r=a+2tb$$ $$\ddot r=2b$$  $$\text {At }t=0, \dot r=a,$$ 
$$\kappa=\frac {2||a \times b||}{(a \bullet a)^{3/2}}.$$

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarification. One question I have is whether it would be okay to treat the vectors as constants during differentiation; I see that the 'OP' vector and the 'a' vector both disappear during differentiation.

Comment: @Peter since there are functions of $t$ ($t^2$, etc) outside of vectors $a$ and $b$, it implies that the vectors themselves do not depend on $t$; therefore their derivatives w.r.t. $t$ will be 0.

Comment: @electronpusher Ahh, I see. Thank you all for clearing things up.